# Is there a like `datacollator` code can apply n-grams masked to masked Language Model using pytorch?

Tags: bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, pre-trained-model

I want apply n-grams masked to masked Language Model in pre-train model using pytorch, Is there source code about it? or Just I must to Implementation it?

This is huggingface's code about `datacollator`.
https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/data/data_collator.py

Thanks very much!

Comment: you could use the ngram function of the nltk package

Comment: Do you means ngram count? But I want n-grams masked in masked language model. I can't get information abount n-grams masked in nltk document... Thanks still